# Sharepoint storage recommendation for recycle bin? (with a storage limit of 10GB)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, onedrive-for-business, storage

Our users from O365 are able to use OneDrive. We set the OneDrive storage limit to **10GB**. In the last few days, some of our users report that they receiving a mail like: `Your onedrive is out of storage space.`

After some analyze, we did realize that this message is because of the content in the `recycle bin`. They were a lot of stuff.

What is the recommendation to set the configuration for recycle bin to not get these kind of messages. And where can I set these settings?

Thank you.

**Edit (additional information):**

Special hint - with this Powershell command I did find some more informations:

> Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $true -Limit All -Filter "Url -like
>   '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'" | SELECT Title, Status,
>   StorageUsageCurrent, LockState, StorageQuota, StorageQuotaWarningLevel

Is there any chance to increase StorageQuoataWarningLevel?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Online, items are retained for 93 days from the time you delete them from their original location. They stay in the site Recycle Bin the entire time, unless someone deletes them from there or empties that Recycle Bin. In that case, the items go to the site collection Recycle Bin, where they stay for the remainder of the 93 days. The Recycle Bin retention time is not configurable in SharePoint Online.

So there are two options for you:

1.Manually delete the items from the recycle bin.

2.Increase OneDrive storage limit.

More information is here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/office-365-sharepoint-online-data-deletion

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you. Is there any chance to create a automate job for cleaning up the Recycle Bin of all OneDrive users? In additional, please check my question again, I have updated it. Maybe you do have any input to this. Thanks.